Saving inputs from a DataGrid to a Database
I am having trouble saving inputs from the DataGrid to my database.
I have the DataGrid which has 6 columns which are IName, QTY, Description, Volume, Unit and Cost.
There is button which allows for the user to add additional rows so they can add more ingredients.
Then I check if the Ingredient already exists by searching IName in the database. If is does exist the IngredientID is retrieved, but if it doesn't exist, I save it as a new ingredient which saves IName, Description, Volume, Unit and Cost (everything but QTY) into tblIngredients.
That happens for all ingredients returning the IngredientID's, these are then saved into tblRecipe which has the columns IngredientID and QTY.
The newly generated RecipeID's (which are automatically generated when adding in IngredientID and QTY) are then saved (separated by comma if more than one) with the remaining columns which are from textbox's.
Below are my three model classes Ingredient, Recipe and Meal, the ingredient view model and the frontend (xaml) and backend code (xaml.cs) of single meal (interface).
public class IngredientsModel
{
    public int IngredientID { get; set; }

    public string IName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }

    public IngredientsModel()
    {
    }
}

public class RecipeModel
{
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }
    public int IngredientID { get; set; }
    public int QTY { get; set; }

    public RecipeModel()
    {
    }
}

internal class MealModel
{
    public int MealID { get; set; }
    public string MName { get; set; }
    public string Cuisine { get; set; }
    public int PrepTime { get; set; }
    public int CookTime { get; set; }
    public int Servings { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
    public object Image { get; set; }

    public MealModel()
    {
    }
}

public class IngredientViewModel
{
    public List<IngredientsData> IngredientsData { get; set; }
    public List<IngredientsModel> IngredientsModels { get; set; }

    public IngredientViewModel()
    {
        IngredientsData = new List<IngredientsData>();
        IngredientsModels = new List<IngredientsModel>();
    }

    public void AddIngredient()
    {
        IngredientsData.Add(new IngredientsData()); // Add a new empty IngredientData object
    }
}

public partial class SingleMeal : Window
{
    private DBConn dbConn = new DBConn();
    private string imagePath = "";
    private IngredientViewModel viewModel;

    public string ingredientName = "";
    public string ingredientDescription = "";
    public string ingredientVolume = "";
    public string ingredientUnit = "";
    public string ingredientCost = "";

    // SQL Connection Script
    private static string SQLConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="
        + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
        + "\\DAL\\YourMealsDB.mdf;" + "Integrated Security=True";

    // New SQL Connection
    private SqlConnection connString = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString);

    public SingleMeal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new IngredientViewModel();
        dataGrid.DataContext = viewModel;
        dataGrid.SelectionChanged += DataGrid_SelectionChanged;
    }

    private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IngredientsData selectedIngredientsData = (IngredientsData)dataGrid.SelectedItem;

        if (selectedIngredientsData != null)
        {
            ingredientName = selectedIngredientsData.IName;
            ingredientDescription = selectedIngredientsData.Description;
            ingredientVolume = selectedIngredientsData.Volume.ToString();
            ingredientUnit = selectedIngredientsData.Unit.ToString();
            ingredientCost = selectedIngredientsData.Cost.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class IngredientsData
    {
        public string IName { get; set; }
        public int QTY { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Volume { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public int Cost { get; set; }
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCuisine.Text) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPrepTime.Text) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCookTime.Text) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtServes.Text) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtKeywords.Text) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagePath) ||
            !viewModel.IngredientsData.Any())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill in all fields and add at least one ingredient.");
            return;
        }
        
        // Save Meal data
        int recipeID = SaveIngredientsAndGetRecipeID();
        SaveMeal(recipeID);
    }

    private int SaveIngredientsAndGetRecipeID()
    {
        int recipeID = 0;

        foreach (IngredientsData ingredientData in viewModel.IngredientsData)
        {
            int ingredientID = GetOrSaveIngredientID(ingredientData);
             
            // Update the existing recipe record with IngredientID and Qty
            RecipeModel recipe = new RecipeModel
            {
                IngredientID = ingredientID,
                QTY = ingredientData.QTY
            };
            dbConn.WriteToRecipeTable(recipe);
        }

        recipeID = GetGeneratedID("tblRecipe");

        return recipeID;
    }

    private int GetOrSaveIngredientID(IngredientsData ingredientData)
    {
        // Check if ingredient exists
        string query = "SELECT IngredientID FROM tblIngredients WHERE IName = @IName";
        int ingredientID = -1;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IName", ingredientData.IName ?? "" );

                var result = command.ExecuteScalar();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    ingredientID = (int)result;
                }
            }
        }

        // If exists, return the existing IngredientID
        if (ingredientID != -1)
        {
            return ingredientID;
        }

        // If not, save to Ingredient table and return the generated IngredientID
        IngredientsModel ingredientToSave = new IngredientsModel
        {
            IName = ingredientData.IName, 
            Description = ingredientData.Description,
            Volume = ingredientData.Volume,
            Unit = ingredientData.Unit,
            Cost = ingredientData.Cost
            // ... set other properties as needed ...
        };

        // Pass the IngredientsModel object to WriteToIngredientTable
        dbConn.WriteToIngredientTable(ingredientToSave);

        ingredientID = GetGeneratedID("tblIngredients");

        return ingredientID;
    }

    // Helper method to retrieve generated IDs
    private int GetGeneratedID(string tableName)
    {
        string query = $"SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('{tableName}')";
        int generatedID = 0;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                var result = command.ExecuteScalar();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    generatedID = (int)Math.Floor((decimal)result);
                }
            }
        }

        return generatedID;
    }

    private void SaveMeal(int recipeID)
    {
        MealModel meal = new MealModel
        {
            MName = txtName.Text,
            Cuisine = txtCuisine.Text,
            PrepTime = int.Parse(txtPrepTime.Text),
            CookTime = int.Parse(txtCookTime.Text),
            Servings = int.Parse(txtServes.Text),
            UserID = 100001, // Replace with actual UserID
            RecipeID = recipeID,
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Keywords = txtKeywords.Text,
            Image = imagePath
        };
        dbConn.WriteToMealTable(meal);
    }

    private void btnUploadImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            imagePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
            btnUploadImage.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath)));
        }
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayTest displayTest = new DisplayTest();
        displayTest.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnAddIngredient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((IngredientViewModel)dataGrid.DataContext).AddIngredient();
    }


XAML view:


             
                 
                 
                 
                 
                 
                 
             
         
         
```
I have tried to save certain inputs to IngredientsData, but I'm struggling with getting all of the rows from the data grid and saving with all the correct ID's (IngredientID, RecipeID).
Any help is appreciated.

I would suggest using en Object Relational Mapper (ORM), like Entity Framework, to help you with converting objects to database queries. That should take care of details like generating IDs etc.
